# Xubuntu stuck in boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu

After removing Ubuntu and successfully installing Xubuntu, when I turn on the Xubuntu logo and the loading symbol, the message "dev/sda8" and something about block and files appears repeatedly no making me reach the login screen. After trying some solutions I noticed that going to "advanced option for ubuntu" and "resume" Xubuntu starts normally but with low resolution.I also tried to reinstall Xubuntu via usb but the same problem immediately came back.

EDIT: In case it helps, this is what I get after typing the command `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
```

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of adding "resolved", "solved", etc. to the question

Comment: Edit: [RESOLVED]